# Вопрос по NS адресам для доменов

Tags: dns

купил сервер, выдали 4 ip. вопрос, могу ли я для каждого домена создавать свои ns адреса на одних и тех же ip.
пример 
первый ip 1.1.1.1 для ns1
второй ip 2.2.2.2 для ns2
есть два домена
a.ru
и 
b.ru
могу ли я сделать так чтобы у a.ru были ns: ns1.a.ru и ns2.a.ru
а у b.ru ns1.b.ru ns2.b.ru ?

Comment: Да, можете конечно

Comment: и эти нс адреса могут принадлеать к одним и тем же ip ? ns1.a.ru и ns1.b.ru r 1.1.1.1, а ns2a.ru и ns2.b.ru r 2.2.2.2 ? )))

Comment: конечно. хотя я все же предпочитаю держать одно имя NS во всех доменах, что бы при смене ip не менять в 10 доменах.

Answer (score 0):

Да, это возможно. Но это не самый лучший вариант.
Лучше всего держать ns сервера на отдельном хосте